# UBER API FEATURES

Tags: javascript, android, json, uber-api

I am building a customized App called "EQZ" for Andrid and will be integrating UBER as a service to call rides for my employees. In the App, once the user has the  called an UBER, the system should exit the UBER platform, log the user out and return to the original EQZ App. Also for users who will sign up to UBER for the first time, we have a credit card swiper that will pull all the persons information and want to save them time for entering all that information manually. Does UBER's API have that feature integrated into it?

Can someone point these things out and show a link or reference that detail what I am requesting and how to integrate these features into our App?

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this functionality with deep links and trip experiences:

https://developer.uber.com/docs/rides/deep-linking-standard
https://developer.uber.com/docs/rides/tutorial-trip-experiences

You can also use the ride request widget to directly embed uber rides widget in your app.